# Right way for backbone view code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a side view list and when one of the item in the list is clicked I show the corresponding view

My code is as follows:

**VIEW**

```
app.View.BrandSidePanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'div',
      template: _.template($('#brand-side-panel').html()),
      template_brand: _.template($('#brand-create').html()),
      template_offer: _.template($('#offer-create').html()),

      initialize: function() {
          this.render();
      },

      events: {
          'click .bra-main': 'showBrandCreateView',
          'click .bra-off': 'showOfferCreate',
          'click .bra-cmgn': 'showCampaignCreate'
      },

      showBrandCreateView: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.reset();
          $('.crt-cnt').html(this.template_brand());
      },

      showOfferCreate: function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          this.reset();
          $('.crt-cnt').html(this.template_offer());
      }, 

      render: function() {
          $('.crt-cnt').html(this.template_brand());
          var $el = $(this.el);
          $el.html(this.template());
          return $(this.el);
      },

      reset: function(){
          $('.crt-cnt').empty();
      }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item bra-main"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;<fmt:message key="brand" /></div>
    <div class="list-group-item bra-off"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;<fmt:message key="brand.offer" /></div>
    <div class="list-group-item bra-cmgn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;<fmt:message key="brand.campaign" /></div>
</div>
```

Everything here is static. Nothing is fetched from the server. I am very new to backbone. The current code works but wants to know if I am doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your side view list won't change in time, it's ok to do it like this, it's just a sort of static menu.

But if the elements in the list could change, you must wrap it in a View and fetch the elements from the server